# File.load() seemingly randomly crashing the program

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

My program has an export / import function that uses [AS3Commons3-zip](http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-zip/) to make zipfiles of some content (pictures, small videos, small pdf's) inside the program. User selects an topic to make the zipfile out of, selects save location, program copies the files to tempDir (with File.createTempDirectory method) and then it loops through the tempDir with following code:

```
         public function fileSelected(event:Event):void{            
        zipFile = event.currentTarget as File;  
        addFileToZip(tempDir, zip);         

    }

    public function addFileToZip(file:File, zip:Zip, path:String=""):void{
        if(file.isDirectory){
            var directory:Array = file.getDirectoryListing();
            filesToCompress = filesToCompress + directory.length;
            dispatchEvent(new 

            for each (var f:File in directory){
                addFileToZip(f, zip, path + "/" + file.name);
            }

            fileAddedToZip();

        }else{
            file.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function():void{

                var pathSplit:Array = file.nativePath.split(".tmp\\",2);
                var fileNamePath:String = pathSplit[1] as String;                   
                zip.addFile(fileNamePath, file.data);
                fileAddedToZip();

            });             

            file.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, function(e:ProgressEvent):void{

                totalLoaded = totalLoaded+e.bytesLoaded;
                trace(totalLoaded+" <---TOTAL LOADED");

            });

            file.load();

        }
    }

    public function fileAddedToZip():void{
        filesCompressed++;

        if (filesToCompress == filesCompressed){

            var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
            stream.open(zipFile, FileMode.WRITE);
            zip.serialize(stream);                  
            stream.close();                             

            tempDir.deleteDirectoryAsync(true);             

        }
    }
```

And the code itself seems to work fine: the zip files import and export perfectly fine. Problem is that the program crashes at seemingly random times. Sometimes it goes through with 30 files, sometimes it crashes with 3. Sometimes it manages to make the same zip from same files 3 times in a row, then it crashes on the fourth try on some file and fifth try crashes on different file.

For example: Five tries with 35 copies of same image exported into the zip:

1. 35/35, TOTAL LOADED trace: 3110337
2. 35/35, TOTAL LOADED trace: 3110337
3. CRASH, TOTAL LOADED trace: 0 after initializing 26 files
4. 35/35, TOTAL LOADED trace: 3110337
5. 35/35, TOTAL LOADED trace: 3110337
6. CRASH, TOTAL LOADED trace: 0 after initializing 14 files
7. CRASH, crashed initializing first file
8. 35/35, TOTAL LOADED trace: 3110337
9. 35/35, TOTAL LOADED trace: 3110337
10. FREEZE WITH NO CRASH (stuck on file 17/35, cancel button works etc.), TOTAL LOADED trace: 1282932

I can see no pattern with it. File.load() method seems to be the culprit but no idea why. Crashes throw no errors at all. Only thing that is certain is that more the image sizes are in total (still under 100MB) the crashes are more common. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by using URLLoader instead:

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(file.nativePath);
            var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(request);

            urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function (event:Event):void {

                var pathSplit:Array = file.nativePath.split(".tmp\\",2);
                var fileNamePath:String = pathSplit[1] as String;                   
                zip.addFile(fileNamePath, event.target.data);

                fileAddedToZip();

            });
            urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
            urlLoader.load(request);
```